# ¿Como ejecutar una funcion Js desde una vista laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, sweetalert2, adminlte

Alguien sabe como puedo llamar funciones js desde la vista de laravel.
Tengo funciones js que ejecuto en las vistas, pero no quiero repetir la misma funcion una y otra vez por cada vista. Estoy usando la plantilla adminlte. y lo quiero es mostrar diferentes alertas de sweetalert2.

Estas son las funciones js que ejecuto en cada vista.

```
    <script>
@if (session('guardo'))
Swal.fire({
  position: 'center',
  icon: 'success',
  title: 'Se ha creado correctamente',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 1500
})
@endif



@if (session('actualizo'))
Swal.fire({
  position: 'center',
  icon: 'success',
  title: 'Se ha Actualizado correctamente',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 1500
})
@endif
</script>
```

Asi es como desde el controllador le paso el dato a la vista, para que la función js se ejecute.

```
return redirect()->route('usuario.index')->with('actualizo', 'ok');
```

o tambien

```
return redirect()->route('usuario.index')->with('guardo', 'ok');
```

Todo funciona, pero no quiero estar colocando la misma logica de js, en cada vista, quisiera tener la logica en un solo lugar, y luego solo llamarla para que se ejecute, gracias.

Comment: En primer lugar, el codigo debiste escribirlo como texto, luego de esos, los `@if` y `@endif` en teoria deberian estar fuera de las etiquetas `<script> </script>`.

Comment: Gracias, actualmente todo funciona, me gustaria saber es como colocar ese codigo en algun lugar fuera, y solo llamarlo desde el js.
Voy a modificar el post. muchas gracias.

Comment: Ponlo el la vista desde donde exitenden todas tus otra vistas.

Comment: mis vistas extienden de mi instalacion de adminLte, si pudiera encontrar ese layout principal, lo colocaria ahi, pero este no es el caso.

por que el "layout" de donde deberia extender, no existe.
envio una muestra de como estoy extendiendo:

@extends('adminlte::page')

busco "page" y no existe.

Comment: Revisa si aparecen esas vistas en `resources/views/vendor/adminlte` después de correr `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\ServiceProvider" --tag=views`,

Comment: cuando ejecuto ese comando me sale:

Unable to locate publishable resources.

Efectivamente ese que tu me ces que es el provider es el que yo tengo, 
https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/wiki/Usage

Ese fue el que usé.

Comment: Gracias a tu respuesta, encontre que podria correr el comando:
php artisan adminlte:install --type=full

y haciendo una copia previamente, para ensayar, sobreescribi todo, a todo lo que me preguntaba le di que si.  cuando ejecuté el comando.

php artisan adminlte:status

Todo esta instalado, excepto justo lo que necesito, las vistas princiapales.

main_views       | The default package main views           | Not Installed | false

Answer (score 1):

Es solo extender la sección 'js' dentro de tu vista blade.

Yo lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
@section('js')
    <script src="{{asset('js/nombrearchivo.js')}}"></script>
@stop
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución para importar las vistas principales, y poder colocar código en el head del proyecto, fue ejecutar el siguiente comando.

```
php artisan adminlte:install --type=full --with=main_views
```